# How can I get data from this object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular

Please help with this. I have an Object that looks like this:

```
data: {
       offersMonday: [
               {
                 "name": "name1",
                 "description" "description 1"
               },
               {
                 "name": "name2",
                 "description": "description 2"
               }
          ],
        offersTuesday: [
        {
                 "name": "name1",
                 "description" "description 1"
               },
               {
                 "name": "name2",
                 "description": "description 2"
               }
          ],
          offersWednesday: [
             {
                 "name": "name1",
                 "description" "description 1"
               },
               {
                 "name": "name2",
                 "description": "description 2"
               }
          ]
}
```

I need to get the description under each objects' instances. What is the best way to do this?

Should I use `filter()` function?

Thanks.

EDIT: **I need to put them all in one variable.** So doing something like `offersMonday[0].description + offersTuesday[0].description` isn't a good thing to handle this.

Comment: How do you want the data to look after you pull it out?

Comment: I'll edit, give me a minute,.

Comment: what do you mean about get this `description` data, what kind of format you want? object, or array?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: What does "in one variable" mean? Do you mean a string that has all the descriptions concatenated? Or an array of strings? Something else?

Comment: a string that has all of them, but I need to use them one by one... Please provide me also with an array solution. Thnks.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Wouldn't an array be a lot more convenient? Can you show an example of what the result should actually look like?

Comment: @eric.dummy called an array

Comment: I need to gather the data and match them with regex in the end..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
data.offersMonday[0].description
```

to read a specific description. Or something like the following to get all the descriptions:

```js
var data = {
       offersMonday: [
               {
                 "name": "name1",
                 "description": "description 1"
               },
               {
                 "name": "name2",
                 "description": "description 2"
               }
          ],
        offersTuesday: [
        {
                 "name": "name1",
                 "description" : "description 1"
               },
               {
                 "name": "name2",
                 "description": "description 2"
               }
          ],
          offersWednesday: [
             {
                 "name": "name1",
                 "description" : "description 1"
               },
               {
                 "name": "name2",
                 "description": "description 2"
               }
          ]
}

var descriptions = [];
for(var key in data){
    data[key].forEach(function(obj){
        descriptions.push(obj.description);
    });
}

console.log(descriptions);
```

Comment: I need to get all of them in one variable.

Comment: @eric.dummy How about the snippet I added?

Comment: Give me a second please.

Answer (score 0):

```
var descs=[];
for(key in data){
  descs=descs.concat(data[key].map(el=>el.description));
}
console.log(descs);//array
console.log(descs.join(","));//string
```

Loop over the main Object, and get all arrays elems description values, and append them to the descs array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
var descriptions = [];
for(prop in data){
    data[prop].forEach(function(offer){
        descriptions.push(offer.description);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I was writing it in the same time and I did not see it!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were missing some `:` marks to format this properly, I've reformatted your input data below:

```
const input = {
data: {
    offersMonday: [{
        name: "name1",
        description: "description 1"
    }, {
        name: "name2",
        description: "description 2"
    }],
    offersTuesday: [{
        name: "name1",
        description: "description 1"
    }, {
        name: "name2",
        description: "description 2"
    }],
    offersWednesday: [{
        name: "name1",
        description: "description 1"
    }, {
        name: "name2",
        description: "description 2"
    }]
}
}
```

Below is a function to move through the object and grab what you need. I removed the "" marks as they're not valid JS (I'm assuming you got this back from JSON). When the JSON object comes in, it'll strip the quotes for you anyhow.

Here's the solution that worked for me, let me know if the format isn't what you're looking for.

```
function groupDescriptions(input) {
  let aggregatedArray = [];
  const data = input.data;

  for (day in data) {
      const innerArray = data[day];
      innerArray.forEach((item) => {
          aggregatedArray.push(item.description);
      })

  }
    return aggregatedArray;
  }
```

`aggregatedArray` returns this:

```
[ 'description 1',
'description 2',
'description 1',
'description 2',
'description 1',
'description 2' ]
```